# How to disable "file risk warning prompt" in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-11, alfresco, regedit

I'm trying to edit a document from an alfresco repository using MS word via the AOS module. Unfortunately I get a warning prompt about this all the time.

[image: File risk warning prompt]

The message in the prompt reads to this effect:

> Some files can harm the computer. If the file information below looks
>   suspicious or if you do not fully trust the source, then do not open
>   the file.

I have so far used inetcpl to configure the trusted sites for the intranet zones and added the domains to the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains
```

following the instructions from [this site](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2012/07/how-to-configuring-ie-site-zone-mapping-using-group-policy-without-locking-out-the-user/) and some others (which all practically allude to the same thing) but so far I have had zero success in disabling the thing.

**OS**: windows 7
**EDCM**: Alfresco 5.2 with AOS
**Browser**: Internet Explorer 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is not in English language, So it is difficult for us to understand which actual error you are getting.

If you are trying to open file via IE and getting security warning for opening a file then you can refer steps below to stop it.

(1) Open **Internet Explorer**.

(2) Go to **Tools**.

(3) Click on **Internet Options**.

(4) Select **Security** tab.

(5) Click button named as '**Custom level**'.

(6) Find an option called '**Launching applications and unsafe files(not secure)**'.

[image]

(7) **Enable** it.

(8) **Restart** the Internet Explorer.

**Note:** It is not recommended to enable this option for a security reason. You can try to make a test with it to check whether it can solve your issue or not.

Comment: I have already tried this. Also the file server resides in an intranet zone so this was enabled for the intranet zone with the zones already defined.

Comment: Can you post your error message in English language? It can help us to understand the issue in better way. Then we can again try to provide further suggestion to solve your issue.

Comment: I already edited the question shortly after my previous reply with the translation of the message.